# Making a PHP MySql search

Tags: php, search, mysqli

I am making a search feature in my app,
i have username ,designation and district,
so could anyone tell me the best approach of achieving it.
It should be like whatever the user enters in search the script should search the database and get the required details.
//my code here

```
<?php
include_once("db.php");
if(isset($_POST['district'])){
    $district=$_POST['district'];
}
if(isset($_POST['designation'])){
    $design=$_POST['designation'];
}
if(isset($_POST['name'])){
    $name=$_POST['name'];
}
if(isset($_POST['department'])){
    $dept=$_POST['department'];
}
$result=array();
$response=array();
if((isset($design)) &&(!isset($district)) && (!isset($name)))
{
    $a=$design;
    $stmt=$db->prepare("SELECT * FROM search WHERE designation LIKE ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("s",$a);
    $stmt->execute();
    $d=$stmt->get_result();
    while($b=$d->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
        $result[]=$b;
}
}
else if((isset($district)) &&(!isset($design)) && (!isset($name)))
{
    $a=$district;
    $stmt=$db->prepare("SELECT * FROM search WHERE district LIKE ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("s",$a);
    $stmt->execute();
    $d=$stmt->get_result();
    while($b=$d->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
        $result[]=$b;

    }
}
else if((isset($name)) &&(!isset($district)) && (!isset($district))){
    $a=$name;
    $stmt=$db->prepare("SELECT * FROM search WHERE name LIKE ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("s",$a);
    $stmt->execute();
    $d=$stmt->get_result();
    while($b=$d->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
        $result[]=$b;

    }
}
if((isset($name))&& (isset($design))){
    $stmt=$db->prepare("SELECT * FROM search WHERE name LIKE ? AND designation LIKE ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("ss",$name,$design);
    $stmt->execute();
    $d=$stmt->get_result();
    while($b=$d->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
        $result[]=$b;
    }
}
if(isset($dept)){
    $stmt=$db->prepare("SELECT * FROM search WHERE department LIKE ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("s",$dept);
    $stmt->execute();
    $d=$stmt->get_result();
    while($b=$d->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
        $result[]=$b;

    }
}
$response['result']=$result;
echo json_encode($response)
?>
```

above is the full code .

Comment: can u please post some code?

Comment: i have tried the simple approach that's simply getting usrrname or district or designation and then doing it maually.

Comment: where is the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you need to change `!empty` and `empty` instead of `isset` and `!isset` because you are setting the variables on the top so it will be always set and will be in each and every condition so I have changed it to empty as shown in code below.

after that, you can make an array with parameters which fulfills the condition and finally I have implemented that in SQL and bind parameter using join, I hope it will work for you.

```
<?php
include_once("db.php");



$result=array();
$response=array();

if(isset($_POST['keyword']) && !empty($_POST['keyword']))
{
    $keyword = $_POST['keyword'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM search WHERE CONCAT(designation,' ', district, ' ', department, ' ',name) LIKE ?";

    $stmt=$db->prepare($sql);
    $key = "%".$keyword."%";
    $stmt->bind_param("s",$key);
    $stmt->execute();
    $d=$stmt->get_result();
    while($b=$d->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
        $result[]=$b;
    }
    $response['result']=$result;
    echo json_encode($response);
} else {
    echo json_encode(array("message"=>"Keyword is not defined"));
}

?>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but the thing i still have to set the $_POST['something'] by my own.isnt there a way it will check the database as a whole and figure out the match also the WHERE .

Comment: what problems are you facing?

Comment: I want to autodetect what the user is searching and then matching it with sql db.

Comment: this is just mysql query for that you need to make ajax request

Comment: i am using this for my android app.so can i use ajax in android as well?

Comment: from android you are sending request and getting some response in json right?

Comment: so before that are you using some tool to check the services like postman or something else?

Comment: then what is the issues you are not getting proper output in postman while searching?

Comment: it works fine like if i set name and put value it then gives me the searched stuff .but what i want is i should only put value without discribing the type of it .and it should check for it

Comment: that means only one search text box should search for every field is it?

Comment: yes definitely the case .or otherwise i have to put something like a dropdown to do this

Comment: it's more simple just do one thing change your search field with named `keyword` and post only keyword field on php side make that changes in your code and postman and I will update the code accordingly I will search in all the database fields with only that `keyword` field

Comment: show me the code how you do that.that would be a big help man

Comment: showing error call to a member function bind_param on boolean on line 14

Comment: if you want to check for more fields in the database then you can add in `concate()`

Comment: yup i have just change the code please make appropriate changes

Comment: 1st shoewed thisshowing cannot pass parameter 2 by reference .Then i removed % from bind it worked but not showing anything

Comment: sorry one more try please check if it is working or not i will look for some change

Comment: Thankyou so much man.It works like charm .you really made my life easy thanks tons

Answer (score 1):

make use of ajax requests.
and your MySql query should be :

`select * from user where uname like %username% or designation like %designation% or district like %district%`

dont forget to use parameterized  queries.

hope that helps.

Comment: how can i check whether the user has entered a username or designation or district

Comment: i have edited the question with my code .take a look

Comment: instead of using multiple if else statements use string concats.

Comment: i mean most apps like flipkart snapdeal and all .it looks like bad ui.if you know what i mean

Comment: yeah i just checked your code,instead of using multiple if else statements use string concats

Answer (score 0):

try this.. I dint execute it.

```
`$query='SELECT * FROM search WHERE ';
$stmt;
if(isset($_POST['district'])){
    $query+='district like @district '
    $stmt=$db->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bind_param(@district,$_POST['district']);

}
if(isset($_POST['designation'])){
    if(strlen($query>27))// district is set
    {
        $query+=' AND ';
    }
   $query+='district like @designation'
    $stmt=$db->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bind_param(@designation,$_POST['designation']);
}
if(isset($_POST['name'])){
    if(strlen($query>27))// district/design  is set
    {
        $query+=' AND ';
    }
    $query+='district like @name'
    $stmt=$db->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bind_param(@name,$_POST['name']);
}
if(isset($_POST['department'])){
  if(strlen($query>27))// district/design/dept  is set
    {
        $query+=' AND ';
    }
    $query+='district like @department'
    $stmt=$db->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bind_param(@department,$_POST['department']);
}
$result=array();
$d=$stmt->get_result();
    while($b=$d->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
        $result[]=$b;
    }`
```

Comment: showed me thisParse error: syntax error, unexpected '$stmt' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\sr.php on line 8

Comment: try adding $stmt=null; and recheck for commas,quotes and semicolons because i did not execute it.

Comment: Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\sr.php on line 9

Comment: The prepare() method can return false and you should check for that. As for why it returns false, perhaps the table name or column names (in SELECT or WHERE clause) are not correct?

Comment: i think it is absolutely perfect.it should'nt have returned false.

Comment: anyways thanks .it still wont work because i have to check what user enter's then pass it to volley as $_POST['something'] .